# itextsharp - problem with memory consumption and long report generation time

Tags: c#, pdf, memory, itext

EDIT: I changed the ending and adds the currency table to the document in a loop and now I don't have a timeout(when I had document.Add(table) once on the ending I had timeout) but it takes 30 minutes and it doesn't end...

```
            currencyTable.AddCell(GenerateCellFromTable(accountTabela));
                        tabelist.Add(currencyTable);
                    }
                }
                //table.AddCell(GenerateCellFromTable(currencyTable));
            }

            
            foreach(var el in tabelist)
            {
                table = InitializePdfTable(8);              
                table.AddCell(GenerateCellFromTable(el));
                document.Add(table);
                document.NewPage();
            }
```

I have a problem with PDF report. My report has 5 levels of headings repeated on each page. (5 x foreach). Raport has 126 pages and  generate takes more than 10 minutes. I cant delete any foreach, there must be this structure.
(when I delete last foreach for tests, report is generated in 2-3 minutes but i cant delete this.. :( )
First 10 pages is EUR currency, 030 account on 3 pages, next 031 etc.

Is there a way to make it generate faster?

Due to the fact that 5-level headers must be remembered, there are reports that generate an hour and more and eat up 10 GB of RAM that they slow down after finishing the report generation..

My raport: (levels highlighted in color - one color is one foreach)

[image]

Code(very simplistic)

```
    private PdfPCell GenerateCellFromTable(PdfPTable pdfTable, int colspan = totalColumn)
    {
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(pdfTable);
        cell.Colspan = colspan;
        cell.Border = 0;
        return cell;
    }
            
     public void GenerateReport()
     {       
            table = InitializePdfTable(8);
            foreach (var currency in currencyList)
            {
                PdfPTable currencyTable = InitializePdfTable();  // DARK BLUE LINE
                pdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(currency.Key, font));
                currencyTable.AddCell(pdfPCell);
                currencyTable.CompleteRow();

                    foreach (var account in currency.GroupBy(x => x.Account.Number))
                    {                           
                        PdfPTable accountTabela = InitializePdfTable();   // BROWN LINE
                        pdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(account.Key, font));
                        accountTabela.AddCell(pdfPCell);
                        accountTabela.CompleteRow();
                            
                            foreach (var subAcocunt in account.GroupBy(x => x.SubAcocunt.Number))
                            {
                            
                                    PdfPTable subAccountTabela = InitializePdfTable(); // GREEN LINE
                                    pdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(subAcocunt.Key, font));
                                    subAccountTabela.AddCell(pdfPCell);
                                    subAccountTabela.CompleteRow();

                                 foreach (var subAccountChild in subAcocunt.GroupBy(x => x.Child.Number))
                                 {
                                        
                                        PdfPTable subAccountChildTabela = InitializePdfTable(); // LIGHT BLUE LINE 
                                        pdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(subAccountChild.Key, font));
                                        subAccountChildTabela.AddCell(pdfPCell);
                                        subAccountChildTabela.CompleteRow();
                                    
                                        
                                            foreach (var subAccountChildChild in subAccountChild.GroupBy(x => x.Child.Number ))
                                            {
                                                PdfPTable subAccountChildChildTabela = InitializePdfTable(); // ORANGE LINE 
                                                pdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(subAccountChildChild.Key, font));
                                                subAccountChildChildTabela.AddCell(pdfPCell);
                                                subAccountChildChildTabela.CompleteRow();

                                                subAccountChildTabela.AddCell(GenerateCellFromTable(subAccountChildChildTabela));

                                            }

                                        subAccountTabela.AddCell(GenerateCellFromTable(subAccountChildTabela));         
                                }

                                    accountTabela.AddCell(GenerateCellFromTable(subAccountTabela));
                            }

                            currencyTable.AddCell(GenerateCellFromTable(accountTabela));
                    }           
                }
            table.AddCell(GenerateCellFromTable(currencyTable))
            document.Add(table);
     }
```

Comment: Have you done any profiling to see what it is that takes so much time? It might be useful to at least confirm that it is the pdf generation and not some data gathering operation.

Comment: I gathering all the data at the start and it takes a few seconds, generating a report with these headers takes so long.I know it because other reports that have 10x more data and 10x more pages but have, for example, one header and 1-2 loops(foreach) are generated in a minute

Comment: It might still be worth doing some profiling, even if only to verify your suspicions. It is fairly common even for very experienced developers to be completely wrong about the reason something takes to long time.

Comment: document.Add(table) takes a long time and consumes all memory

Comment: iText (in particular iText before version 7) is not optimized for complex nested tables spanning multiple pages. Try simplifying your architecture so that tables span not more than a few pages and avoid nesting them. Also consider making use of the fact that `PdfPTable` implements `LargeElement` and add it piecewise.